# Can one run Elementary within VM

Tags: dual-boot

I would like to run Elementary on my MacBook Air via VM such as Virtualbox.

Can this be done, and where should I look for detailed assistance ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Installing VirtualBox is pretty easy: just follow the instructions on the program's website [VirtualBoxForMacOS](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Mac%20OS%20X%20build%20instructions).

If you are asking how to install elementary is in VirtualBox:

1. Download the ISO from [elementary.io](https://elementary.io/).
2. Run VirtualBox and choose New.
3. Select your system name and type of system (I usually choose Linux x64).
4. You see the creation wizard for the virtual machine. If you just need a default machine then go next, next, next and maybe you will want to just adjust the amount of RAM and the size of the virtual hard disk.
5. When finished, highlight your new VM and choose Storage from menu, then click icon with CD and choose .iso file.
6. Run the VM.
7. You are now in the system installation. :)

Answer (score 0):

*EDITED*

You don't even need to do all that building from source and installing macports, just snag the binary from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads then install and run, I would recommend grabbing the extension pack for it as well.

Comment: Sorry, yeah to clarify, you don't need to build it from source, or use macports.